# Vector Space - how to visualize it for understanding?

Tags: vector-spaces

I read on Wikipedia about vector spaces, but I don't understand them in a way that I can visualize the vector spaces in my head. During the process of understanding, I had several concepts in my head and I am at a point now, where I am totally confused. Maybe I am in a dead end as well. I have drawn four of these concepts, so you can imagine what happened in my head.

**Pictures:** [my approaches for vector spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGkAN.jpg)

**Picture A**
$ \vec{r} $ is the vector space, which means the space is linear on the line of the vector. $ \vec{r} $ contains infinite vectors like $ \vec{a} $, $ \vec{b} $ and $ \vec{c} $. The last three vectors only exist in $ \vec{r} $ or vector spaces which are bigger or equal to themselves. An orthogonal vector of $ \vec{b} $ is not a part of $ \vec{r} $.

**Picture B**
The vector space is an area where one or multiple vectors like $ \vec{r} $ and $ \vec{m} $ exist. The space is infinite, which doesn't make much sense to define a space. But it is a space. In the picture it is the striped zone of the diagram.

**Picture C**
$ \vec{r} $ can be build by the linear combination of $ \vec{a} $ + $ \vec{b} $, $ \vec{c} $ + $ \vec{d} $ or any other combination of two vectors within the red striped zone. But what is with combinations outside of the red striped zone? Here it destroys my concept probably.

**Picture D**
$ \vec{r} $ is the shortest vector to the target point. $ \vec{a} $, $ \vec{b} $, $ \vec{c} $ and $ \vec{d} $ are one linear combination of multiple possible linear combinations to the target. Is the red striped area the vector space or red and yellow together?

Is one of my concepts the right concept of vector spaces?

I really appreciate your inputs and hope to get a explanation which my brain can visualize. Maybe you could draw it?

Comment: Don't use an arrow do denote a vector space, as it is not itself a vector.

Comment: @K.defaoite r, m, a, b, c, d should be vectors in a vector space. Shouldn't write them as vectors with an arrow? I know that these vectors are not the vector space itself. Exception is r in picture A. Hope this clarifies or didn't I understand you in the right way?

Comment: For a finite-dimensional real vector space, I gained intuition by picturing a bead that I could slide along (or parallel to) wires pointing out from a particular point (the origin or zero-vector). I start at the zero vector and slide the bead a distance $c_1$ along direction $\mathbf{u}_1$. From there, I slide a distance $c_2$ parallel to the wire pointing in direction $\mathbf{u}_2$. I keep doing that until the arrow pointing from the origin to my bead is $c_1\mathbf{u}_1 + \cdots + c_n\mathbf{u}_n$, where each $\mathbf{u}_i$ is a unit vector.

Comment: @JoeMac If I understand you right, you add normalised vectors (distances) and the sum is the vector space? This reminds me a little bit to **picture A**. EDIT: But a distance with the dimensions of the vectors.

Comment: I have been using the terminology for so long that it can mean only very specific things to me. I may not be interpreting your statements correctly. Consider a 2-d plane with a particular point that we call the origin. The collection of all arrows that point from the origin to **any point** in the plane is a vector space. Each arrow is a vector and is a member of this collection. As @k-defaoite mentioned, $\vec{r}$ is a vector, not a vector space. The vector **space** is the "list" of all vectors that exist. _Space_ = "List of vectors"; _Vector_ = "Element of 'list'"

Comment: @JoeMac Okay, I think I got it. It is a list of all possible vectors. In V = R is the number of possible vectors infinite, until I restrict the vector space with further conditions. That is why it can simply visualized, cause its all or nothing.

Comment: All vector spaces "over" $\mathbb{R}$ (except for the vector space consisting of the zero vector alone) have an infinite number of members. While $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers, is a vector space "over" itself, I suspect that you might still be a little fuzzy on the difference between the vector space and the field that it is "over". $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, the field of real numbers. In that case, $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $K = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are primary examples of vector spaces (over the real numbers):

- A one point set, regarding the point as the origin, i.e. the zero vector $\{0\}$. This space is $0$ dimensional.
- A full line through the origin (basically it's along the lines of your picture A, but we also consider negative and *every* multiples of its vectors). The lines are $1$ dimensional.
- A full plane through the origin, including all its points. These are $2$ dimensional.
- The physical 3d space you can consider as a $3$ dimensional vector space after fixing a point for origin: you can add vectors and multiply them by real numbers: that's what the abstract definition says.

We can observe that in all these geometric examples, the elements of the given set can be *coordinatized* by base vectors, namely we have to fix exactly as many base vectors as the given 'dimension'.
This, on one hand, means that the elements of the given set can be represented by a single coordinate (for a line) / a pair of coordinate numbers (for a plane) / a triple of coordinates (for the space).

But this thing we can simply continue in the algebraic way:

> For any positive integer $n$, we can define a (canonical) $n$ dimensional vector space: $\Bbb R^n$ consists of the $n$-tuples of real numbers. You can add them and multiply by any real number, coordinatewise. You can check the conditions that it indeed defines a vector space in the abstract sense.

Comment: This answer is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A, B are reasonable pictures.

C, D are not.

the vector space is the set of all linear combinations of some set of basis vectors.

That means that the vector space is never bounded in the way you have it pictured in these two pictures.  If $a$ and $b$ are in your space, so is $2a$, and $2b$ and $a+b$ and $\frac 12a + 3b$ etc.  And in D) $r, c, d$ can each be described as some combination of $a,b$

Comment: That means, that the vector space depends on the base vectors, not the actually vector which is build by the base vectors. Am I right?